# ZF2 application on Openshift: 404 not found when not '/'

Tags: php, .htaccess, zend-framework2, http-status-code-404, openshift

I have just deployed a small ZendFramework 2 application on Openshift [here](http://zf2demo-dawningstreams.rhcloud.com/).

The main page is properly displayed, but when I try to log in, I get a 404 not found. The URL is `/authenticate`. In fact any non `/` url does not work.

Why?

**Update**

My `http.conf` contains:

```
DocumentRoot ${OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR}/public
<Directory "${OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR}/public">
    Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.cgi
AccessFileName .htaccess
<Files ~ "^\.ht">
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Files>
```

and there is a `.htaccess` in `/public`:

```
RewriteEngine On
# The following rule tells Apache that if the requested filename
# exists, simply serve it.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
# The following rewrites all other queries to index.php. The 
# condition ensures that if you are using Apache aliases to do
# mass virtual hosting, the base path will be prepended to 
# allow proper resolution of the index.php file; it will work
# in non-aliased environments as well, providing a safe, one-size 
# fits all solution.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)(.+)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in my `http.conf`, I changed `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All`.